# Syntax error , python, for syntac error

Tags: python

I try to fill new column in csv file ( 'light_during_5hours_ago') depending on the time column but before 5 hours, if the record in light column was one , then put 1 otherwise put 0, I got this error?

File "", line 11
    for csvfile.seek(testdata.Time<=t):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

here is my code and part of file

```
with open('G:/testdata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    with open('G:/testdata1.csv', 'w') as csvoutput: 
        row.append('light_during_5hours_ago')

        for row in csvfile:
            row_identify = row[0]
            row_identify1 = row[1]
            for row in csvfile:
                for row_identify in row:
                    for csvfile.seek(testdata.Time<=t):
                        if row_identify1 =='1':
                            row.append(1)
                                else:
                                    row.append(0)
                                    all.append(row)
        writer.writerows(all)
```

Data:

```
Time    light   lock    ismart
3/26/2018 6:16  1   0   0
3/26/2018 6:17  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:40  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:40  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:40  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:40  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:40  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:40  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:40  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:40  1   0   0
3/26/2018 7:41  1   0   0
3/26/2018 8:52  1   0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csvfile.seek(testdata.Time<=t)` is not an iterator; you can't use it as the control of a `for` loop.  Note the difference in expression from your previous statement.  I suspect that you've left out a variable, such as

```
for dummy in csvfile.seek(testdata.Time<=t):
```